# Buddhist Centres in Paris?

Tags: vipassana, zen, meditation-recommendation, insight

I moved to France, Paris recently. I am seeking any meditation centres vipasana, zen, Insight etc., where I can also communicate in English, since I don't speak much French.

Can anyone here who knows about any such places or websites please let me know?

Answer (score 4):

I had success with http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/ when looking for local communities. In fact, this is how I found my last Zen Master.

Here is a direct link to Paris page, there are 13 centers registered: http://www.buddhanet.info/wbd/province.php?province_id=761

Answer (score 3):

If you've gone through a [10-day Vipassana course](http://www.dhamma.org/) ([available in France](http://www.dhamma.org/en/locations/directory), but not in Paris), you can take a [1-day Vipassana course for old students in Paris](http://www.dhamma.org/en/schedules/schmahi#paris.fr). They're both in French and English.

Answer (score 2):

I had the best retreat experience of my life at plumvillage.org - near Bordeaux. I think there's more than one Paris sangha of the Plum Village order. I don't want to sound like a proselytizer, but in my opinion, any serious practitioner must spend some time if possible with Thay.

Speaking English should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Triratna centre in Paris](http://www.centrebouddhisteparis.org). The people that I know who are running it speak English, but their website is in French and I'm not sure about what language is used in teachings etc. (never been there myself unfortunately).

Regards, Kusalananda