# Meditation Retreat in India

Tags: theravada, personal-practice, vipassana, meditation-recommendation, monastery

Are there any good places for meditation retreats in India ? ( Theravada/Vipassana ) Could someone share their personal experience ?

Comment: Is this Off topic / too specific?

Comment: @AndreiVolkov given that this question remained open I would say this one should too http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2349/157 though TBH I though the Paris one should have been closed and I was surprised it wasn't. That probably doesn't help :-)

Comment: Agreed, closing this one would not be consistent with that other decision. Although it is not clear to me if both are appropriate...

Comment: I'm not hugely fond of this style of question, going to take it to a [meta question](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/280/32).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list of center can be found in:

- https://www.dhamma.org/
- http://www.buddhanet.net/

Also it is best not to discuss meditative experiences and many traditions forbid this as individual experiences differ from one person to another since the sum total of your Sankara (conditioning /fabrication) differs. When you discuss experience what happens if people crave for different experiences and your meditation becomes unsuccessful.