# Finding a Sangha in London

Tags: vipassana, sangha

I've been what you might call an armchair Buddhist for many years. I'm at a point where I'd really love to meet other like minded people and get involved with the Buddhist community on a more personal level.

I live in London. Having listened extensively online to Dharma talks from wonderful teachers like Gil Frondsal, I can see there are a great many communities in the United States which spread the Dharma. I was wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of similar communities in the UK, specifically London?

Comment: See also [Buddhist Centres in Paris?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2349/254)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW, some good resources are linked over there.

Answer (score 2):

I've been to [London Buddhist Centre](http://www.lbc.org.uk/) and that was very good. It's part of the [Triratna Buddhist Community](https://thebuddhistcentre.com/text/what-triratna-buddhist-community) and it's explicit aim is to present the Buddha's teaching in a way that is compatible with modern society. It's in a converted fire station so it's a really good space and it was friendly when I went.

I am biased though - I'm involved with Triratna in Leeds so it's my sangha. I think it's still a good recommendation though.

Answer (score 1):

Try www.samatha.org with some experienced local groups.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not in London but not too far away are two monasteries well worth the trip.
Amaravati (http://www.amaravati.org/)
Cittaviveka (http://www.cittaviveka.org/)

There is also London Buddhist Vihara (www.londonbuddhistvihara.org/) closer to home.